# unexpected EOF on the last and next to last line while creating alias

Tags: 14.04, bash, alias

I am creating alias in `.bash_aliases` file in Ubuntu 14.04 with reference of [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/73768/how-to-use-aliases-to-customize-ubuntu-commands/)

I write these

```
alias agi='sudo apt-get install'
alias upd8='sudo apt-get update'
alias perms='stat -c '%a - %n'
alias dwld='cd ~/Downloads'
alias ..='cd ..'
alias la='ls -alh'
alias hf='history | grep $1'
alias pf='ps -e | grep $1'
```

I close the terminal and file and start the terminal it always gives error.

> bash: /home/ice/.bash_aliases: **line 8:** unexpected EOF while looking for matching 
>   `''
>   bash: /home/ice/.bash_aliases: **line 9:** syntax error: unexpected end of file

Please note there is not a **line 9**, no white space, no special character

*What I have done so far*

- Removed white space new line and space between lines.
- Remove last two lines but then error comes on last and next to last line ( 6 & 7)
- Deleted the temp file on same folder ending with `~` but error remains.
- Removed the `..` and `la` alias line ( may be it can cause issue) but error still remains.
- I have created an alias with `perms` from terminal before the creation of `.bash_aliases` so removed that alias using `unalias perms`
- check all alias using `alias` and it show only first 2 alias andd interestingly first two aliases are working fine.

Is this some kind of bugs or what?

Comment: So what's the new problem? Did you start a new shell?

Comment: @muru it was the quotes error as you answered. Thanks for the quick response. I just addded two more action what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax highlighting that Stack Exchange offers is enough to see what's wrong. It's this line:

```
alias perms='stat -c '%a - %n'
```

The quote isn't closed. Try:

```
alias perms='stat -c "%a - %n"'
```

Comment: Thanks :). I also seen the highlighted syntax, it's just superb. You save my day